# How can I put placeholders for numbers in google translate API?

Tags: google-translate, google-translation-api

I have an Android-style string along the lines of say:

`You got %1$s questions out of %2$s correctly`

how do I pass this string in google translate API to get a correct translated string with placeholders?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html5 translate attribute:

```
You got <i translate="no">%1$s</i> questions out of <i translate="no">%2$s</i> correctly
```

The API should not translate what's inside the html tag. 
Finally, you can remove the html tags added with a regex in the translated string.